# Laravel 5.5 named route with parameters in mailables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.5

According to documentation, everything should work fine... However.. it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong or is it actually a bug?

**Relevant model: Invitation**

```
class Invitation extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'invite_code';

    protected $fillable = ['invite_code', 'creator_id', 'expires_at'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'expires_at'];

    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        return $this->attributes['invite_code'];
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
    }
}
```

In routes (web.php) I have:

`Route::get('/register/{invitation}', 'Auth\RegisterController@showInvitation')->name('invitation.show');`

And the same functions are used in view and a view in mail:

`{{ route('invitation.show', ['invitation' => $invitation]) }}`

In the regular web view the route generates properly:

`http://host.local/register/PCBIIHW12e6GBSaK`

In the email the route shows:

`http://host.local/register/0`

Also this little snippet in routes :

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', function($id) {
    $i = \App\Invitation::find($id);
    dump( $i->invite_code );
});
```

dumps out (with a proper model loaded)... dum-dum-dum - `0`;

Migration (just in case)

```
Schema::create('invitations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('invite_code')->primary();
    $table->integer('creator_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->dateTime('expires_at');
});
```

Anyone can actually explain what's going on?

Comment: show me the controller

Comment: public function showInvitation(Invitation $invitation)
    {
        if ($invitation->expires_at < Carbon::now()) {
            return view('auth.invitation.expired', ['invitation' => $invitation]);
        }
        $invitation->load('user');
        return view('auth.invitation.index', ['invitation' => $invitation]);
    }

Comment: check values of `$invitation` in mail view

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting as it seems it's now working. I've changed the schema by renaming the field to `token` instead of `invite_code` ... and... it's all working as intended... weird.

Solution - do not use double words as RouteNameKeys...